# CMD - Script for checking machine-type automatically

Tags: windows, script, cmd.exe

I work at a school and a lot of my work consists of updating, configuring and reformatting computers.

I have created a script to do most of the work, but among other things, Ii still have to choose the computer model manually every time. I found this script by Googling, but I need some help to optimise it for my situation.

I have about 9 different models I need to support and more to come in the future, so it would have to be easy to add new models. Here is what i have found so far:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a IN ('wmic computersystem get model /format:list') DO SET SYSMODEL=%%a
SET SYSMODEL=%SYSMODEL:  =%
ECHO %SYSMODEL%

SET 120L=Latitude 120L
SET MODEL=%SYSMODEL%

echo.%120L% | findstr /C:"%MODEL%" 1>nul

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  GOTO :D531_NEXT
) ELSE (
  GOTO :120L_OK
)
```

How can I make this more efficient?

It works ok, but I would imagine it would be quite inefficient to run this string for every computer model I have?

EDIT: This seems to work ok: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423443/switch-statement-equivalent-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: What exactly is this script supposed to do? It has errors, eg "The system cannot find the batch label specified - 120L_OK" and you are not using "120L" ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Okey, i will try to explain better. 

This script is supposed to check what the "wmic computersystem" returns and if it matches what is written in line 4, then it will GOTO a specific location of my choosing. Don't worry about GOTO not working and the missiong ", i will sort that out later. I would like some input on how to make this more efficient.

Comment: [switch statement equivalent in Windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18423443) might give you some ideas. See also http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html and http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php for other ideas ...

Comment: Thanks for the input. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423443/switch-statement-equivalent-in-windows-batch-file) by DavidPostill looks like it did the trick!